# How to make JAR from package?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, jar, ant

I have a Spring MVC web project having many packages. I want to make a JAR file of only one of those packages. This package has no main class.

How to make the JAR of only this package?

Comment: what is the purpose of making the jar file ? is it a maven project ?

Comment: Yes Sir, it is maven project .  I want to use the classes from this package in another project so I want to make jar of this package and then use it in other package

Comment: I do not know intelliJ and therefore not sure if there is an easier way, but of course a `jar` is a zip file so you could build the whole `jar` and remove stuff that you do not need

Comment: i think these classes must be using some other jars as well , so its better that you create a separate maven project and include this as a maven dependency wherever you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include below code snippet in the pom file of the project.

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/package1/*</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

You can modify "package1" in the above code to your specific package name. Then the resulting jar file contains only classes from the specified package.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by including/excluding resources under the build tag:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>YOUR PACKAGE PATH TO BE INCLUDED</directory>
        <includes>
           <include>**/*.java</include>
            ... you can add more extensions to be included in your jar
        </includes>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>YOUR PACKAGE PATH TO BE EXCLUDED</directory>
        <excludes>
           <exclude>**/*</exclude> // to exclude all content from other packages
        </excludes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```